# A generalization of an old group problem

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Here is an old exercise in group theory: **(1) If $G$ is a group of order $2n$ with $n$ odd then $G$ is not simple and in fact $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $n$**. I am going  for one straight generalization: **(2) If $G$ is a group of order $2^kn$ with $k\geq 1$ and $n$ odd then $G$ is not simple and has a normal subgroup of arder $n$**. The proof of (1) would use the fact that $G$ must have an element of order $2$. So I don't think that (2) is true (even I have no counterexample yet). Now in (2) lets assume that $G$ has an element of order $2^k$. Does it make (the new) (2) a ture statement ?!

Comment: Any finite group of even order has order $2^kn$ with $k\ge 1$ and $n$ odd, so of course any non-abelian simple group is a counterexample to your "straight generalization". Boris' reply is an answer to the last question (with the additional assumption of existence of an element of order $2^k$).

Comment: See math.stackexchange.com/questions/55964

Answer (score 4):

See a proof in: http://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2011/01/30/groups-with-a-cyclic-sylow-p-subgroup-2/

A more general situation see in:

Wong, W.J. On finite groups whose 2-Sylow subgroups have cyclic subgroups of index 2. 
J. Aust. Math. Soc. 4, 90-112 (1964).

Comment: Do you know any example to show that "**having an element of order $2^k$**" is necessary ?

Comment: No, I don't know. I think it is not necessary.

Comment: But both solutions that you have mentioned above use this assumption very essentially.

Comment: Yes, however...

Comment: @nadal, (2) is not true (without additional assumptions); see Yves's comment.

Comment: Of course having an element of order $2^k$ is not necessary to have a normal 2-complement, just consider the direct product of a non-cyclic 2-group and any group of odd order.